# How to check ClearType status through WMI/CIM

Tags: windows, fonts, cleartype, wmi

So I wanted to know if anyone knows if it is even possible to check the status of ClearType on a windows pc using WMI or CIM and if so, which subcategory I would have to look in?

All I have been able to find with Google and WMI explorer is WIN32_FontInfo which just tells me which fonts is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, it seems this is only doable through the registry, not to mention super tricky to do programatically, so set it and cross your fingers.